# Packing and unpacking float values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, struct, hex

Why does python return "odd values" when I try packing a `float` object? For example:

```
>>> import struct,time

>>> struct.pack('d', time.time())
b'\xe0LC|\xf6l\xd7A'

>>> struct.unpack('d', b'\xe0LC|\xf6l\xd7A')
(1572067825.051567,)
```

Why does it unpack the value as a tuple instead of a float? And then, why does it use values such as `LC` and `|` and `l` -- I thought it would pack the items in hex?

Comment: Structs can represent more than one value and are this always tuples. Packing returns bytes, not hex - bytes are displayed as ASCII with special symbols escaped as hex codes.

Comment: Are you asking "why" as in "what did I do to make this happen" or "why did they decide to implement it that way"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of unpack states explicitly that the result is a tuple:

> Unpack from the buffer buffer (presumably packed by pack(format, ...)) according to the format string format. The **result is a tuple** even if it contains exactly one item. The buffer’s size in bytes must match the size required by the format, as reflected by calcsize().

You can see the representations of all possible bytes with:

```
for i in range(256):
    print("{} : {}".format(i, bytes([i])))
```

For instance, `124` is represented by `b'|'`. In your case, `b'\xe0LC|\xf6l\xd7A'` is the representation of `bytes([224, 76, 67, 124, 246, 108, 215, 65])`.